# How does pandas know the type of aggregation function?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I tried to calculate how frequent my feature is in the dataframe.
For that I tried to use *obviously wrong* function.
(Yes, I know it doesn't aggregate, as I said, obviously wrong)

```py
def virus_p(count):
  return count / count.sum()
```

(If you didn't read my previous sentence, I'm not asking what is the problem with my function, I'm asking how pandas knows that there is a problem. It's a theoretical question, not a "practical" one).

For minimal reproducible example.

```py
def virus_p(count):
  return count / count.sum()

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 10],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 5],
])
df.columns = ['virus', 'days']
df.groupby('virus')['days'].agg(virus_p)
```

It didn't work and it failed with "Aggregation function must produce aggregated value".
I then tried to put print(count) in my function to at least understand the data I work with.

But surprisingly I got an error before it printed anything, which means that pandas scanned my function behaviour even before it was called.
I'm not always that lucky to get an error, and all other times I just write something that passes pandas "typecheck", but then falls because I got the wrong argument (and probably because my function logic is just wrong).

But the question is, how does pandas know what my function produces in Python, a dynamically typed language where an object may have whatever type it wants, and you can't know before you execute it?
Does it have mini-mypy inside?

UPD: I can't reproduce this behaviour anymore (I tried in Google Colab), but the question still stands. Pandas documentation says that the function must work either when passed a DataFrame or when passed to DataFrame.apply. And first works on DataFrame, the second on series.

Comment: There's no aggregation in your code so far. Also, for function that return a series of the same size as the group, better off with `.groupby().transform()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang, I know, that's why I said my function is obviously wrong. It's just way too hard to wrap my head around aggregation when I don't understand the function type I must write.

Comment: Hi Julian. It will be great if you can add a [mcve].

Comment: @rpanai yep, I guess that would be useful. Added.

Comment: *"Pandas documentation says that the function must work either when passed a DataFrame or when passed to DataFrame.apply."* That's what it says for `pd.DataFrame.agg`, but in your example isn't it `pd.Series.agg` that's relevant (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html), because `['days']` selects an individual column, i.e. a Series?

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your behavior. Pandas doesn't parse your code before but sometimes it can catch an exception and call your function back with another form. This is for example the case of the `date_parser` parameter of the `read_csv` function.

Try this to hide the full traceback:

```
import pandas as pd

def virus_p(count):
    print(count, flush=True)  # not mandatory but...
    return count / count.sum()

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 10], [1, 2], [2, 5]], columns=['virus', 'days'])

try:
    df.groupby('virus')['days'].agg(virus_p)
except ValueError as err:
    print(err)
```

Output:

```
0    10
1     2
Name: days, dtype: int64
Must produce aggregated value
```

Comment: Strange, now I get the same behaviour, I guess there was a problem with output not printing for some reason? But I'm still not sure how pandas knows out what function expects. Does it just guess that function expects the whole dataframe and if catches an Exception, tries to pass it to each column? Or the other way around.

Comment: Like `groupby_transform`, the function should receive a Series as first parameter.